# Inconsistent results for f(g(x)) together or split up

Tags: r, random, random-seed

During [a recent investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31063419/3093387) into setting random seeds within functions, I came across an odd situation. Consider functions `f` and `g`, each of which sets the random seed and then performs a simple randomized operation:

```
g <- function(size) { set.seed(1) ; runif(size) }
f <- function(x) { set.seed(2) ; x*runif(length(x)) }
```

Because each function sets the random seed, I would expect each function to always have the same return value given the same input. This would mean `f(g(2))` should return the same thing as `x <- g(2) ; f(x)`. To my surprise this is not the case:

```
f(g(2))
# [1] 0.1520975 0.3379658

x <- g(2)
f(x)
# [1] 0.04908784 0.26137017
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is an example of the double-slit R experiment. When x is observed, it acts as a particle; when unobserved it acts as a wave. Behold

```
g <- function(size) { set.seed(1) ; runif(size) }
f <- function(x) {set.seed(2) ; x*runif(length(x)) }
f2 <- function(x) {print(x); set.seed(2) ; x*runif(length(x)) }

f(g(2))
# [1] 0.1520975 0.3379658

x <- g(2)
f(x)
# [1] 0.04908784 0.26137017


f2(g(2))
# [1] 0.2655087 0.3721239
# [1] 0.04908784 0.26137017

x <- g(2)
f2(x)
# [1] 0.2655087 0.3721239
# [1] 0.04908784 0.26137017
```

I'm just josilbering you. `print` is forcing `x`. You can do that explicitly

```
f <- function(x) {force(x); set.seed(2) ; x*runif(length(x)) }
x <- g(2)
f(x)
# [1] 0.04908784 0.26137017
```

But not this

```
f(force(g(2)))
# [1] 0.1520975 0.3379658
```

Comment: LOL. The double slit experiment in R! Lazy evaluation as QM. Perfect.

Comment: Nice usage of `josliber` as a verb.

Comment: @JosephWood I like to think that all the upvotes were for that

Answer (score 24):

The `x` argument of your `f()` function is only evaluated at the moment that it is actually used inside the function. This means that the `set.seed(2)` is evaluated **before** the execution of the `g()` function when you try to compute `f(g(2))`.

```
> f(g(2))
[1] 0.1520975 0.3379658
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
> set.seed(2)
> set.seed(1)
> result <- runif(2)
> result*runif(length(result))
[1] 0.1520975 0.3379658
```